# RuntimeError: Working outside of request context. in flask error

Tags: web, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am getting this error while running flask.
**RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.**

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\BISMILLAH\Desktop\projects\project1\project1\application.py", line 18, in

```
session(app)
```

File "c:\users\bismillah\desktop\itachi\personal.ru\anaconda\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 376, in

```
__call__ = lambda x, *a, **kw: x._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)
```

File "c:\users\bismillah\desktop\itachi\personal.ru\anaconda\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 307, in _get_current_object

```
return self.__local()
```

File "c:\users\bismillah\desktop\itachi\personal.ru\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 38, in _lookup_req_object

> raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)

RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.

Comment: plz **help** me out

Comment: Please read: [How to ask ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)